# Value undefined for a particular @Input parameter

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am having a below component in my AngularJs 2 based Ionic 2 project.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'items-list',
  templateUrl: 'items-list.html'
})

export class ItemsListComponent {
  @Input() type;
  @Input() count;

  items: Array<{ url: string, title: string }>;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.type); //undefined
    console.log(this.count); //10

    this.items = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < this.count; i++) {
      this.items.push({
        url: 'assets/' + this.type + '/' + i + '.png', title: 'Style # ' + i
      });
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.items));

  }
}
```

I am using the component in one of my page as below and it shows up the template content.

```
<items-list [type]="children" [count]=10></items-list>
```

But the "type" input value is always undefined. I am able to see the value of "10" in the console for "count" input.

Why "this.type" is always undefined and why "this.count" shows the actual value?

Comment: what's the `type` value at parent component?

Comment: The value being passed at parent is "children" as mentioned in question.

Comment: What is `children`? how you do assign value? did you check if it's `undefined` in parent or not?

Comment: Hope I have explained what I have and how I check for value in console.

Comment: You added code of child component and you are receiving `undefined` means something wrong at parent component.

Comment: That's what the question is about :) I am not sure what's the issue in my code. BTW I am new to Angular 2.

Comment: I agree with @SefaÜmitOray.  Something wrong with ur parent code.Share ur parent code.

Comment: I can see what's the question and i'm asking for paren components to solve it. :) Your child component is fine. Need to see the parent component.

Comment: There is no parent component. I am using the component in a page which is provided.

Comment: Or please explain what you mean by parent component

Comment: You are using `items-list` element in a template. That template is controlled by a component. That component is called parent component and your `items-list` is child since it's declared inside of some other component.

Comment: Data is passed from  parent to child with input binding.
see this link: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child

Comment: I am sorry friends. I am not using any other template. I am using this component in a Ionic Framework.

Comment: Let's try this step by step :) Where does `children` comes from?

Comment: The string value of "children" is hard coded in the Ionic page.

Comment: Can you add code of that ionic page?

Comment: <items-list [type]="children" [count]=10></items-list> is the code present in the ionic page.

Comment: I am confused because one of the Input works and not the other in the same component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with a component I created.  If your type is a string, don't use `[type]="children"`, use `type="children"`

Comment: Wow. You saved me, my lord :) Thanks for your easy tip for this learner.